# Database design SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

Say I have a database with multiple entitles like `person, company, conference` for which you have to keep track of say `addresses`. We can have multiple addresses for the same entity (person). One approach is to have a separate address table for each entity (person_address etc). Another approach is to have an address table which has primary key (`Entity,id,address_type`). In this approach we cannot use foreign keys from address table to entities .

So what is the better approach. Is there another way to do this ?

thanks

Comment: at 2000 rep, you've been around long enough to know better than to tag a question `sql` and `server`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At a logical modeling POV your descriptions highlights the fact that the entities like `person`, `company`, `conference` etc have a common trait: they have zero, one or more addresses. If you would model this as a class hierarchy, perhaps you would create an `Addressable` class and have person, company and conference inherit from this Addressable class. You can apply the same reasoning to your data model and have an `addresable` table with an `addressable_entity_id`. The `person`, `company`, `conference` entities would 'inherit' this table. There are three established ways to implement table inheritance:

- [Class Table Inheritance](http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/classTableInheritance.html)
- [Single Table Inheritance](http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/singleTableInheritance.html)
- [Concrete Table Inheritance](http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/concreteTableInheritance.html)

So you could model your tables like this:

```
create table Addresses (AddressId int not null identity(1,1) primary key, ...);
create table Addressable (AddressableId int not null identity (1,1) primary key, ...);
create table AddressableAddress (
    AddressId int not null,
    AddressableId int not null,
    constraint AddressableAddressAddressId
        foreign key (AddressId) references Addresses(AddressId),
    constraint AddressableAddressAddressableId
        foreign key (AddressableId) references Addressable(AddressableId));
create table Person (PersonId int not null identity(1,1) primary key,
     AddressableId int not null, 
     ...,
     constraint PersonAddressableAddressableId
         foreign key AddressableId references Addressable (AddressableId));
create table Company (CompanyId int not null identity(1,1) primary key,
     AddressableId int not null, 
     ...,
     constraint CompanyAddressableAddressableId
         foreign key AddressableId references Addressable (AddressableId));
```

Of course you have to find the right balance between absolute relational normal form and actual usability. In this scheme I propose for instance in order to insert a new Person one has to first a row in Addressable, get the AddressableId and then proceed and insert the person. This may or may nor work. BTW, there *is* a way to do such an insert in one single statement using the OUTPUT clause to chain two inserts:

```
insert into Addressable (AddressableType)
 output  inserted.AddressableId, @FirstName, @LastName 
 into Person (AddressableId, FirstName, LastName) 
values (AddressableTypePerson);
```

But  now is difficult to retrieve the newly inserted `PersonId`.

Answer (score 1):

Technically if two people live at the same address you would not be completely normalized if there was simply a single one-to-many detail table for the row in `TBLPerson` called `TBLAddress` However, if you want just one instance per physical address you will incur the overhead of a many-to-many relation table of `TBLPersonAddresses` which FK's to `TBLAddress`

I would say that unless you expect multiple people at the same address to be the norm that I would simply have the `TBLAddress` with column `personID` as a detail to the `TBLPerson`

**EDIT:** And I tend to always use surrogate keys unless I have a specific reason not to do so.